# How to test a function which returns anonymous function in jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, d3.js, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a function which returns an anonymous function. The problem i am facing is that the test doesn't cover the return part of the function which is returning the anonymous function.
code-

```
tweenPie = (b) => {
    const { arc } = this;
    b.innerRadius = 0;
    let i = d3.interpolate({ startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0 }, b);
    return (t) => arc(i(t));
  };
```

test

```
  test("spy on tweenPie function", () => {
    const wrapper = setup();
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "tweenPie");
    wrapper.instance().tweenPie({});
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

my test doenst cover the line  return (t) => arc(i(t)); in the function. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tweenPie` actually doesnot return a value but returns another `function`. So, when you call `wrapper.instance().tweenPie({});`, you get a function and not a value.

Inorder to test that function, just make another call, like below.

```
// Pass some value that corresponds to t in (t) => arc(i(t));
wrapper.instance().tweenPie({})(t);
```

Comment: Welcome @akshatgupta.